# IntelliSense suggest only one option

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

In VsCode, whenever I try to use `IntelliSense` at the end of:

- an object to see its methods,
- an structure to see its components or
- a path to see its directories,

`IntelliSense` only suggests me one result at a time, so I have to hit <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate through the results until I eventually find what I was looking for.

[image: .gif demonstrating IntelliSense]

This is quite not ideal... Is there a way to configure VsCode so that it pops a tap with all options, instead of one at a time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be you just need to resize it with the new resize ability.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_resizable-suggestions

Comment: bruh I cant believe that it was it hahaha awesome, the easiest the best. thank you!